# Cisco VRF aware dynamic VTI based IPSEC VPN

Tags: cisco, ipsec, vrf

im struggeling on a Cisco IPSEC Konfiguration.

My aim is to terminate spoke sites behind CGN gateways into a MPLS L3VPN Network via IPSEC tunnels.

The router at hub site is a ASR1k running IOS XE 3.16
Spoke site routers are random, im currently testing with a C819 4G model.

Here is my hub site configuration:

`!
crypto keyring KEYRING

  pre-shared-key hostname router1-xxx key somekey
!
crypto isakmp policy 103
 encr aes 256
 authentication pre-share
 group 5
 lifetime 7200
! 
crypto isakmp profile IKEPROFILE
   keyring WISY-TURIN-KEYRING
   match identity user-fqdn router1-xxx
   virtual-template 103
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set AES_256-SHA ah-sha-hmac esp-aes 256 
 mode tunnel
!
crypto ipsec profile IPSECPROFILE
 description some description
 set security-association lifetime seconds 7200
 set transform-set AES_256-SHA 
 set pfs group5
 responder-only
!
!
interface Virtual-Template103 type tunnel
 description some description
 vrf forwarding CUSTOMER
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.252
 tunnel source Loopback0
 tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
 tunnel protection ipsec profile IPSECPROFILE
!`

Here the spoke configuration

     `crypto isakmp policy 103
      encr aes 256
      authentication pre-share
      group 5
      lifetime 7200
     crypto isakmp keepalive 10
     !
     crypto isakmp peer address 212.218.X.X
      set aggressive-mode password somekey
      set aggressive-mode client-endpoint user-fqdn router1-xxx 
     !
     !
     crypto ipsec transform-set AES_256-SHA ah-sha-hmac esp-aes 256 
      mode tunnel
     !
     crypto ipsec profile WIPSECPROFILE
      description Wirth Systems Standort Turin
      set security-association lifetime seconds 7200
      set transform-set AES_256-SHA 
      set pfs group5
     !
     !
     interface Tunnel0
      ip address 10.1.1.2 255.255.255.252
      ip nat outside
      ip virtual-reassembly in
      tunnel source Cellular0
      tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
      tunnel destination 212.218.x.x
      tunnel protection ipsec profile IPSECPROFILE`

Phase1 is coming UP OK, but i have issues bringing Phase2 up.

Here is the output of

```
show crypto ipsec sa
```

at the hub router:

`interface: Virtual-Access2
    Crypto map tag: Virtual-Access2-head-0, local addr 212.218.X.X`

protected vrf: CUSTOMER
   local  ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/0/0)
   remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/0/0)
   current_peer 5.90.X.X port 500
     PERMIT, flags={origin_is_acl,}
    #pkts encaps: 0, #pkts encrypt: 0, #pkts digest: 0
    #pkts decaps: 0, #pkts decrypt: 0, #pkts verify: 0
    #pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
    #pkts not compressed: 0, #pkts compr. failed: 0
    #pkts not decompressed: 0, #pkts decompress failed: 0
    #send errors 0, #recv errors 0

```
 local crypto endpt.: 212.218.154.5, remote crypto endpt.: 5.90.10.185
 path mtu 1576, ip mtu 1576, ip mtu idb GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 current outbound spi: 0x0(0)
 PFS (Y/N): N, DH group: none

 inbound esp sas:

 inbound ah sas:

 inbound pcp sas:

 outbound esp sas:

 outbound ah sas:

 outbound pcp sas:
```

So no SA is created. I'm also confused about the fact that this output says

```
PFS (Y/N): N, DH group: none
```

although PFS is configured.

```
debug crypto ipsec
```

brings following output:

`*Jun 30 18:42:05.074: IPSEC(validate_proposal_request): proposal part #1,
       (key eng. msg.) INBOUND local= 212.218.X.X:0, remote= 5.90.X.X:0,
         local_proxy= 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/256/0,
         remote_proxy= 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/256/0,
         protocol= AH, transform= NONE  (Tunnel-UDP), 
         lifedur= 0s and 0kb, 
         spi= 0x0(0), conn_id= 0, keysize= 0, flags= 0x0
     *Jun 30 18:42:05.075: IPSEC(validate_proposal_request): proposal part #2
     *Jun 30 18:42:05.075: IPSEC(validate_proposal_request): proposal part #2,
       (key eng. msg.) INBOUND local= 212.218.X.X:0, remote= 5.90.X.X:0,
         local_proxy= 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/256/0,
         remote_proxy= 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/256/0,
         protocol= ESP, transform= NONE  (Tunnel-UDP), 
         lifedur= 0s and 0kb, 
         spi= 0x0(0), conn_id= 0, keysize= 256, flags= 0x0
     *Jun 30 18:42:05.075: Crypto mapdb : proxy_match
        src addr     : 0.0.0.0
        dst addr     : 0.0.0.0
        protocol     : 0
        src port     : 0
        dst port     : 0
     *Jun 30 18:42:05.081: IPSEC(key_engine): got a queue event with 1 KMI message(s)
     *Jun 30 18:42:05.081: Crypto mapdb : proxy_match
        src addr     : 0.0.0.0
        dst addr     : 0.0.0.0
        protocol     : 256
        src port     : 0
        dst port     : 0
     *Jun 30 18:42:05.081: IPSEC(crypto_ipsec_create_ipsec_sas): Map found Virtual-Access2-head-0
     *Jun 30 18:42:05.082: %ACE-3-TRANSERR: IOSXE-ESP(14): IKEA trans 0xC30; opcode 0x60; param 0x1F79; error 0x5; retry cnt 0
     *Jun 30 18:42:05.082: %ACE-3-TRANSERR: IOSXE-ESP(14): IKEA trans 0xC32; opcode 0x60; param 0x1F7A; error 0x5; retry cnt 0`

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for all replys.

Comment: You may be running into this bug.  Remove one of the transforms from your transform set: https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/lan-switching-and-routing/ike-phase-2-sa-expires-immediately-site-2-site-ipsec-over-gre/td-p/2087058

Comment: OMG... i foud this bug also while googleling but did't get the solution. o_O ... changed ah-sha-hmac to esp-sha-hmac and it works... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cisco bug on ASR1k that causes issues in IPSEC over GRE configuration with AH and ESP Mixed configuration
CSCtb60545 / CSCsv96390

changed ah-sha-hmac to esp-sha-hmac in the Transform-set configuration which solved the issue.